# Java: Initialize condition in If construct (performance)

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am looking for a possibility to initiate a variable in the if condition, so it is only valid in the scope of the condition.

Example: I want to transform this:

```
String tmp;
if ((tmp = functionWithALotOfProcessingTime()) != null)
{
    // tmp is valid in this scope
    // do something with tmp
}
// tmp is valid here too
```

Into something similar like this:

```
if ((String tmp = functionWithALotOfProcessingTime()) != null)
{
    // tmp is *ONLY* in this scope valid
    // do something with tmp
}
```

Comment: That's just not how Java's scoping rules are defined.

Comment: The compiler will automatically limit the scope of a variable to where it is used.  BTW This has no impact on performance, only only limiting the use of a variable to where it is intended to be used.

Comment: There are no performance issues involved in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
{
    /*
     * Scope is restricted to the block with '{}' braces 
     */
    String tmp; 
    if ((tmp = functionWithALotOfProcessingTime()) != null) {
        // tmp is valid in this scope
        // do something with tmp
    }
}

tmp = "out of scope"; // Compiler Error - Out of scope (Undefined)
```

Comment: I don't want an extra scope, it messes up the readability of the code

Comment: In that case, its not doable with if blocks. Scope is just an alternative.

Comment: @Eun You clearly want an extra scope, and in Java you do it with the braces.

Comment: Accepted, since it is the closest answer, btw I know what I want and what I don't.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two ways to do it:

- You need an extra scope, `{...}` or `try{...}catch...` and declare the `tmp` in that scope.
- wrap your `if` logic in a private method, and declare the `tmp` in the method, so that in your main logic, you cannot access `tmp`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest leveraging the Optional API:

```
Optional.ofNullable(functionWithALotOfProcessingTime()).ifPresent(tmp -> {
   // do something with tmp
});
```

Note: Optional was introduced in Java 8.